# How one can calculate $s_2(p)$

Tags: binary

Let us define the integer $p$ as follow:

$$p= \sum_{i=1}^{m}(2^{k+2})^{i}-r2^{k+2}-2w+1+3a$$

How one can calculate $s_2(p)$ the sum of binary digits of $p$. Here all the arguments are integers.

Comment: So after calculating $p$, one writes it in binary and then adds the $1$'s?

Comment: @calculatormathematical: I have saw this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295048/calculate-the-sum-of-the-binary-digits-of-x-n3-being-x-n-an-integer-expres

Comment: Ok, can you still add some context to your question?

Comment: @calculatormathematical: Ths is an exercice

Comment: Great, add the book or source, give some details, maybe its a number theory book or an olympiad exercise, how did you stumble upon it, what have you tried? And please put some brackets in your sum.

Comment: @calculatormathematical: This is in arabic and no book is refered. Just a series of exercices.